# Nextjs 13 Api With passport

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am working on converting the site version from next js 12 to the latest version 13
But I had a problem converting this api to the latest version

```js
import { passport } from "@/lib/auth";
import nc from "next-connect";

const handler = nc();
handler.post(passport.authenticate("local"), (req, res) => {
  res.json({ user: req.user });
});
```

As we know, the new api method is like this

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function POST(request) {
  const { title, content } = await request.json();

  // logic to create a post in database

  return NextResponse.json({   });
}
```

Thank you